Facing setupProxy issue in my react application
I'm facing an issue in my react application where I have created setupProxy.js file in that I have added multiple environment url (.development, .test) . Development port is running "http://localhost:8080 & test is running "/bizcomp.test.com". When I run my app using test env (non-prod) its working properly but if I run my app using backend port (8080) path is not accepting. Please find below setupProxy.js & error screenshot.
Below is the api call which we use in frontend
http://localhost:8080/bizcomp/restservices/v1/service/seller/comptitle.
Note: Issue which I'm checking "/bizcomp" path in setupProxy is working. But I run my app using test env "/bizcomp" is working properly.
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');

module.exports = function (app) {
  let targetUrl; 

  // Set the target URL based on the current environment

  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
    targetUrl = "http://localhost:8080"
  } else if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'test') {
    targetUrl = process.env.REACT_APP_OIDC_REDIRECT_URI;
  } else {
    console.error('Unknown environment:', process.env.NODE_ENV);
    return;
  } 
  console.log(`Proxying requests to: ${targetUrl}`);

  // Proxy API requests to the backend server
  app.use(
    '/bizcomp',
    createProxyMiddleware({
      target: targetUrl,
      changeOrigin: true,
      secure: false, // Disable SSL verification if necessary
      onProxyReq: (proxyReq, req, res) => {
        console.log(`Proxying request: ${req.method} ${req.url}`);
      },
      onError: (err, req, res) => {
        console.error('Proxy error:', err);
        res.status(500).send('Proxy error');
      },
    })
  );
};



your question doesnt make sense, appreciating you might be ESOL prehaps get some help writing it in the staging ground. In your error log the response shows a 400 error meaning the request sent an invalid payload. you need to look at the network tab and determine what was sent to the endpoint and if the endpoint returned any specfic error relating to what it could not process.

If I use same proxy in package.json it will work. But when I use backend port in setup proxy '/bizcomp' path which I'm passing weather it is not accepting. @Phil

Exactly what proxy value in package.json works?

@Phil http://localhost:8080

If I add this 8080 in setupProxy it will not work because I'm passing path /bizcomp its not matching with my current api path

What does the request from the client-side look like?

Please [edit] your question to include an example of a request from your React app's code

The way http-proxy-middleware works is by proxying the request path that comes after the base path provided and passing that to the upstream target.
For example with
app.use('/bizcomp', createProxyMiddleware({
  target: 'http://localhost:8080',
});

Only the part after /bizcomp in the original request is sent



Original Request
Proxied Request




http://localhost:3000/bizcomp/foo/bar
http://localhost:8080/foo/bar



If you want to keep that base path in the proxied URL, you need to include it in the target
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
  targetUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/bizcomp';
}

Unfortunately this is not well documented.

As an aside, Create React App is unmaintained and no longer a recommended option for starting React apps.
See this answer for some references and recommendations.

@abhijitbakshi you're welcome. Another aside, you might want to check your localhost:8080 service. I would have expected it to respond with a 404 for incorrect URLs instead of a 400

I have question. In my application we have 3 non-prod environment, local environment and prod environment

@abhijitbakshi the comments section is not the place to ask further questions. If you other problems they should be asked in their own post(s)
